# Mocking autowired field in the method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I was wondering whether there's a way to mock the field which is being autowired.

Consider the following case.

I have a class name A

```
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public void aMethod() {
         b.method();
    }
}
```

The other class B looks like this

```
public class B {

    public void method() {
    // some code
    }
}
```

Now i want to write junit for the method.

I know there's a way to mock the autowired field like this.

```
public class TestA {

   @InjectMock
   private A a;

   @Mock
   private B b;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void testAMethod() {
        // write test case.
    }

}
```

But my question is -> Is there a way to mock the autowired field inside method after creating object with new.

eg

```
public class TestA {


    public void testAMethod() {
       A a =new A();

       // how to mock the B instance in it.

    }

}
```

Please suggest or there's no way to do this????

I dont want to change from private modifier. Nor i want to add getter's and setters or reflection. I just want to know is there a way to mock the B instance after creating the new object of A class.

Comment: Would you be happy to use reflection? Other way would be to make it protected, have your test class extend A and set it directly.

Comment: No i want to do it without reflection or changing the modifier.

Comment: There's no way to access a private field without reflection. If there was a way, private wouldn't mean private anymore.

Answer (score 0):

How about [ReflectionTestUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html)?

```
A a = new A();
B b = mock(B.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(a, "b", b);
```

It's still reflection-based and has all related drawbacks, though it's quite simple and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with mockito, this would require to modify the bytecode of the class being tested. However Powermock allows such stubs. Note though that I and the creator of Powermock - Johan Haleby - would push for a refactoring instead of using Powermock. Powermock is very powerful, maybe too much, and working allows anyone to write legacy code, that would be difficultly maintainable or extensible (property you can find in poorly designed legacy code).

In your case I don't know what's wrong in your case with the dependency injection. However if the code need a new instance of `B`, it may be useful to have inject in `A` a factory/provider/builder class which will make a new instance of `B`. Such code can be easily stubbed with Mockito.